# understanding of the notifyDataSetChanged on a listview

Tags: android, listview, refresh

I trying to refresh the listview if the data got changed.

```
lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mMyAdapter=(ListAdapter) new ImageAndTextListAdapter(this, total_list);
         lv.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);
        ((ArrayAdapter<ImageAndText>) mMyAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So, in this case, the data is the total_list, and if it got changed then adapter would notify the listview and then the listview would refresh automatically ? or I need to add something there?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) this is what should happen. If it does not happen, then it's most likely an error in Android (As it seems like it were [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/56e527cdcf249ca2) in Android 1.6). Meaning, that you are correct in your assumption, but errors do sneak in - but are probably solved by now. :)

Answer (score 1):

notifyDataSetChanged() is used to tell the listadapter that the dataset you provided it has changed. This tells the listadapter that it needs to reload the data. This is important since a lot of the defaults for listadapters include using caching. notifyDataSetChanged() should only be called after data is actually changed.